# Turn Mp4 File into Portrait Video

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I recently programmed a bot, which uses the Twitch API to scrape Twitch videos, and then post them on YouTube. This is my youtube channel if you want to see an example: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuhWw8LbPWdkybIF9olAszw

The problem that I am having is I want to find a way to convert these regular twitch videos, into youtube shorts which I can automatically upload. The facecam does not need to be included, and the entire video can just be compressed into a 9:16 format.

I already tried FFMPEG but I don't know if I am doing it correctly, and really need help or advice on how to do this.

Here is an example of a video I would try to convert:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZecXrvd6_g

(excuse the explicit language, this is just the first video I saw on my bot channel)

**Tldr: Convert mp4 file into a 9:16 video format**

EDIT:

Command i ran: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale=1280:720 output.mp4

Comment: Please edit your post to include what you tried (the ffmpeg command) with an explanation of how it doesn't meet your expectation

Comment: Done @Kesh. I added the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current command loses the display aspect ratio.

There are 4 basic filters for video size manipulation:

- [`scale`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1) Scale the input video dimension. Use `iw:-1` or `-1:ih` to maintain the aspect ratio
- [`pad`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad-1): Add paddings to the input image (increase the frame size)
- [`crop`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop): Crop the input video to given dimensions (reduce the frame size)
- [`setsar`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setdar_002c-setsar) Always follow a `scale` filter with `setsar=1/1` to keep the pixel shape square.

Read the documentation on their options and examples. You can chain these filters to accomplish your goal.

So, let's say going from a portrait video to 720p (1280x720). The first thing is to scale the input to have the height of 720px (while maintaining the aspect ratio). Then pad horizontally to fill 1280px columns. Here is the filtergraph:

```
-vf scale=-1:720,setsar=1/1,pad=w=1280:h=720:x=(ow-iw)/2:color=violet
```

You just chain these filters with commas. Note that many ffmpeg filter options accepts expressions (e.g., ow=output width, iw=input width) so you don't need to compute the exact number yourself.

Like this, just plan your sequence of actions to get the desired effect. Sketching the shape of the video after each frame will help you understand what you are doing. Good luck.

Comment: When I run this command in terminal, it says "zsh: no matches found: scale=-1:720,setsar=1/1,pad=w=1280:h=720:x=(ow-iw)/2:color=violet". This is what I am running: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale=-1:720,setsar=1/1,pad=w=1280:h=720:x=(ow-iw)/2:color=violet output.mp4. Am I doing it right?

Comment: See if double quotes around `scale=...violet` helps. I'm assuming that you have successfully run ffmpeg command. If not, do your research and get yourself up to that point.

Comment: Adding double quotes around scale=...violet worked, but i'm trying to go from a landscape video (sorry, in the title I meant landscape), to a portrait. So 1280 x 720 to 720 x 1280. I want the video to remain the same, but just padding around the video to change. What command would you recommend in this case? I already tried a few commands such as ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale="-1:1280,setsar=1/1,pad=w=720:h=1280:x=(ow-iw)/2:color=violet" output4.mp4, but it didn't work. Thank you so much for helping me - I gave you the green checkmark, because your answer did help. Thanks!

Comment: The scale filter must work with the smaller of the two (so basically flip the scale options in my example) then the pad filter in y direction not in x.

Comment: That worked @kesh. Last thing though: How do I put the video in the center of the padding? So that there is padding above and below the video? Thank you so much Kesh!

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? In my example I centered it using `x=(ow-iw)/2`. `ow` is the output width and `iw` is the input width of the video. You need to convert it to the height equivalence

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much Kesh for all of your help!